# Group by and summarise number of boolean values of a column corresponding to each unique value of another column on a specific date

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

I have the following data frame:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(tibble)
data_frame <-
  tribble(
    ~id,     ~date,                       ~boolean_value,
    "1",     as.Date("2020-01-01"),       TRUE,
    "2",     as.Date("2020-01-02"),       TRUE,
    "2",     as.Date("2020-01-02"),       TRUE,
    "3",     as.Date("2020-01-02"),       TRUE,
    "3",     as.Date("2020-01-03"),       FALSE
  )
```

I want to be able to group by the `date` column and summarise by the number of unique ids as well as the sum of the boolean values that correspond to each unique occurrence of `id`. However, when I run the following code, it gives me the sum of `boolean_value` corresponding to each `date`.

```
data_frame %>% 
  group_by(date) %>% 
  summarise(
    total_ids = n_distinct(id),
    total_true_values = sum(boolean_value)
  )
#> `summarise()` ungrouping output (override with `.groups` argument)
#> # A tibble: 3 x 3
#>   date       total_ids total_true_values
#>   <date>         <int>             <int>
#> 1 2020-01-01         1                 1
#> 2 2020-01-02         1                 3
#> 3 2020-01-03         1                 0
```

Instead, I want to know the number of `TRUE` values on each date for every unique occurrence of `id` on that date. I am expecting the following result:

```
 #> # A tibble: 3 x 3
    #>   date       total_ids total_true_values
    #>   <date>         <int>             <int>
    #> 1 2020-01-01         1                 1
    #> 2 2020-01-02         2                 2
    #> 3 2020-01-03         1                 0
```

How can I achieve this with using dplyr/tidyverse? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can subset the 'id' based on the logical vector and get the `n_distinct`

```
library(dplyr)
data_frame %>% 
   group_by(date) %>% 
   summarise(total_ids =n_distinct(id), 
              total_true_values = n_distinct(id[boolean_value]))
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 3 x 3
#  date       total_ids total_true_values
#  <date>         <int>             <int>
#1 2020-01-01         1                 1
#2 2020-01-02         2                 2
#3 2020-01-03         1                 0
```

Comment: @akun in case that i have another `id`, lets say `id` 4 on 2020-01-02 that also has a TRUE boolean value, your code will only display a value of 1 for `true_values` for `2020-0-01`, whereas I want to have `true_values` for that date to be equal to 2, since there are 2 TRUE values that correspond to 2 different `id` on that date. How do i calculate that? thanks for your help!

Comment: @UsmanKhaliq FOr the `total_ids`, isn't it 2 for the second row?

Comment: my apologies, yes it is 2, ive updated the dataset now.